# localStorage clears variable just seconds after storing it

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to utilize the localStorage in a chrome browser to implement a login feature using Angular. I'm using this resource as reference: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial.

The problem is when I save a variable in localStorage using

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
```

the app passes authentication and redirects to a welcome screen. However, in the chrome dev tools->application->Local Storage->http://localhost the variable appears and then disappears in about a second. I verify that it is no longer saved becuase trying to refresh redirects me back to the login page.

Why would the localStorage be clearing my data when nowhere in my code do I call localStorage.clear?

I even downloaded Jason Watmore's github project from the link above and when running that application I get the same problem. 
To reproduce:

1. run app in chrome
2. login using the given credentials
3. view localstorage from chrome dev tools
4. refresh page and it will ask to login again

### EDIT :

It appears to be working now and I have no idea why. What I did was restart my computer, and consequently the my servers as well and now the variable remains in localStorage as expected. If anyone could shed some light on what was going on under the hood I would be grateful.

Comment: Try looking at the network traffic.  If the browsers is not getting a session cookie, it might be think that a new request is happening therefor a fresh page?

Comment: I tried that, but I only saw one request so that may not be it.